# Careers 2.0 expects responses to generic form messages?

Tags: support, jobs

I keep getting emails reminding me that I have message on Careers 2.0, and that I should respond even if not interested so the employer can continue their search. This doesn't make much sense to me, as the message resembles a generic job posting and is in no way tailored to my profile. I am quite confident that many people got an identical message, and the employer is not waiting for my response before taking further measures to fill their position.

If an employer were to specifically target me, with a custom message selling the job as a good fit for me based on my profile, I would be happy to reply even to let them know I wasn't interested. But I don't think I should be nagged to respond to a generic message.

What is the vision of how Careers 2.0 is supposed to work, and does it really include expecting people to respond as "not interested" to generic messages? If it does, why isn't there a "not interested" button to send a generic "not interested" response?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each message you receive, you will be nagged to answer exactly twice (once at 4 days and once at 10 days after the initial message).  The purposes of the nags are two fold:

1. Remind you about the message (maybe you missed it or it was lost in transit)
2. Remind you about your search status (whether you're actively or passively looking) on careers so you can update it if necessary.

If you haven't responded to the message after the second nag, we set your search status to passive.

> ...does it really include expecting people to respond as "not interested" to generic messages?

It surely does. We're trying to maintain a healthy ecosystem of candidates and employers. We keep track of statistics on how candidates are responding to employers' messages.  If you think a message is bad, tell **us** about it by replying not interested with the "This position does not appeal to my interests at all" option.

[image: Not Interested Reasons]

When enough of these pile up for a particular employer, we'll get in touch with them about their messaging and try to get them to change their behavior to be more candidate friendly.

A no response doesn't give us any information as to how you think the employer is acting. We can't help fix something we don't know is broken.

Comment: That makes sense, but it seems your reasons for wanting a response is different than what is stated in the email, and this is confusing. Also, this being the first message I have received on Careers 2.0, I did not expect hitting the reply button to have those radio buttons. You may want to consider how you help new users get started and nudge them along, because I don't think the current process communicated your intended message to me.